# How do I get vbscript to save variables into a text file and recall them when reopening the program?

Tags: list, text, vbscript, save

I'm still pretty fresh at making programs and I prefer to type out my codes. I'm trying to make a "save" file and I would like for somebody to point me in the right direction as far as how to save a list of variables under a "username" and recall them later (as needed) after closing and reopening the program. Separate .txt files would be preferred. For example:

```
title: username24.txt
username24
yes
no
17
blue
555-624-9652
[blank]
first last
```

and similar data.

Answer (score 3):

Plan:

1. use array to store the data
2. use FileSystemObject to read/write
3. use Split/Join to (un)stringify the data

Demo:

```
Option Explicit

Const csFiNa = "username24.txt"
Const cnName = 0
Const cnTStamp = 1
Const cnBlank = 2
Const cnYesNo = 3

Dim oFS : Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim aData : aData = Array("username24", Now, "", True)
If oFS.FileExists(csFiNa) Then aData = Split(oFS.OpenTextFile(csFiNa).ReadAll(), vbCrLf)
aData(cnTStamp) = Now
aData(cnYesNo) = Not aData(cnYesNo)
WScript.Echo Join(aData, ", ")
oFS.CreateTextFile(csFiNa, True).Write Join(aData, vbCrLf)
```

Runs:

```
cscript 00.vbs
username24, 4/4/2013 7:50:14 AM, , False

type username24.txt
username24
4/4/2013 7:50:14 AM

False

cscript 00.vbs
username24, 4/4/2013 7:50:47 AM, , True
```

Comment: This is a step in the right direction, I will work with this and see where it takes me, thank you.